# Vista shutdown hung after 200 updates

Tags: windows-vista, windows-update, shutdown, hung

I've recently reinstalled Vista with SP2 on an old laptop to try resolve numerous issues for a friend.

Afterwards I installed all the drivers from the manufactures websites with no problems.

I started the windows update, the check took no less than 20 hours! Finding 201 updates, the download took about 1 hour 30 minutes, at which point I opted to install during the shutdown and go to bed. (Noting it had dropped to 200 updates for some reason?)

I awoke this morning to find it's hung on the 'shutting down...' screen. Left it for a few hours not knowing when (or if) it finished the updates.

Is it save to force shutdown, or should I leave it? I'm not in any rush.

---

**UPDATE**

After waiting 9 hours the laptop fan stopped spinning and after a further 3 hours I did a force shutdown.  Tried to boot into safe mode but it took longer than normal and reset itself during the boot, during the second boot it started up the 3 step install screen, but failed on step 2 and now it's on a screen I've not seen before saying...

> Updates were not configured correctly.  Reverting changes.
>   Do not turn off your computer.

Since we're taking about 200 updates I'm guessing this will never finish reverting!!  Anybody seen this before and know how long it takes?

I think I'm going to opt for buying a cheap windows 7 product key.  Does anyone know if you can do a clean install of windows 10 with a windows 7 product key?  Or do you have to first have windows 7 installed?

---

**UPDATE 2**

If anyone is interested the revert only took about 2-3 hours.  But I'm not letting it try install all 200 again, just going to try a windows 7 install instead.

Comment: It's safe to assume it's hung... though It would be also reasonably safe to assume it's struggling for memory & might take ages. If you're really in no rush give it another day. If no change, not even a number 'Installing 2 of 200...' etc then power it off & see if it will boot...

Comment: @tetsujin the force shutdown failed, see update on question.

Comment: If there's nothing on there you care about, then blow it away in favour of a fresh win7 sp1 would seem to make most sense. You could do 10, but having had a couple on test here for nearly a year... I wouldn't yet.

Answer (score 2):

While I have seen this on Vista, in the dim and distant past, I have had this happen to me, regularly, on new installs of Windows 7, from an original initial release DVD, which then have to go through *all* of the updates, from scratch, including SP1. I found that, on *every* install, the updates would hang somewhere about 150 updates in, in a very similar manner to which you are describing. It is as if there are a few mutually exclusive "locks" at a certain point during these mega updates, where the updates may end up conflicting with eachother, and Windows gets itself into a bit of a *tizz*.

I would forcefully shut the PC down, after having waited innumerable hours, and upon startup Windows would be, initially, somewhat confused, but eventually sort itself out, after re-enumerating which updates has successfully been installed and which had not.

I suspect that Vista does the same enumeration of completed updates.

---

If the machine really does end up getting confused then this guide could help, [Windows updates stuck on Shutdown or reboot – “Installing Update…”](http://blog.techygeekshome.info/2014/09/windows-updates-stuck-on-shut-down-or-reboot-installing-update/).

> Do not turn off your machine or reboot it as you will just get stuck
>   on the “Installing Updates…” message again. The reason this is
>   happening is because of a corrupt update or a corrupt update database.
>   Either way, the fix is pretty simple if you have a basic understanding
>   of computers.
>
> There is a folder under the Windows directory called
>   “SoftwareDistribution”. This folder is where all Windows Updates are
>   downloaded to and run from as well as the Windows Update database
>   being in here. So, if it is corrupt, we need to get rid of it and
>   recreate it from scratch – this will fix your problems.
>
> First of all, you cannot just go in and delete or rename the folder,
>   there is a Windows Update service running that will stop you from
>   doing this. So, the plan is to stop the service, rename the current
>   folder, start the service again which will then in turn recreate your
>   SoftwareDistribution folder and Windows Update database.

Open an Admin Commnad prompt and run

```
net stop wuauserv
ren c:\windows\softwaredistribution sd.old 
net start wuauserv
```

> Once this has restarted, you should now notice that the
>   SoftwareDistribution Folder has been recreated – you should now
>   restart your computer and you should notice that it reboots without
>   any problems.
>
> But wait – there is one last thing that you need to be aware of. As
>   you have now completely removed the old SoftwareDistribution database,
>   when you next run Windows Updates, it will not know that it has been
>   run before and may through an error. Ignore this and just click “Check
>   for Updates”. It will then check the machine, see that it has a number
>   of updates and catch up with itself again.

---

As an aside, I would recommend that you do not use Vista, unless it is for a Vista specific bug tracking or support issue, and upgrade to Windows 7 instead - it is much more efficient and stable. Vista was arguably, one of the worst versions of Windows that was ever released, on a par with ME.

It could boost performance if you can find a dirt cheap old Windows 7 disk, with license, on eBay or in a market. I have a lot of old laptops that were designed for XP, and they run Windows 7 just fine - however, Vista just made them run dog slow

Comment: +1 Re Vista!  It's a friend's laptop, the laptop itself isn't worth installing anything on, but he can't afford to upgrade.

Comment: @Skytunnel - Ah, I see, well that is a shame, but it could boost performance if they can find a dirt cheap old Windows 7 disk, with license, on eBay or in a market. I have a _lot_ of old laptops that were designed for XP, and they run Windows 7 just fine - however, Vista just made them run dog slow.

Comment: that's a good idea, hadn't thought of that.  Will suggest that too him.  Thanks

Comment: the force shutdown failed, see update on question.

Comment: @Skytunnel - hmm, not good